# Multiple checkbox management

Tags: html, css

Hello I generate my checkboxes using this way.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
                $i=1;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="'.$row['type_id'].'" id="'.$row['type_name'].'">'.'
                <label for="'.$row['type_name'].'" class="fil_lab">'.$row['type_name']. '</label>';
                if($i%5==0) 
                {
                 $i = 0;
                 echo '<br><br>';
                }
                $i++;}
```

Note that they will most likely generate 50+ checkboxes. Currently they are generated by 5 each then next line and the way they are set up they are inconsistent with one another and are hard on the eyes. Would anyone know how to fix this so that they would be properly structured?[Link to screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ARrC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to give the checkbox a width and the label a width. That way they tale up the same amount of space.

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="'.$row['type_id'].'" id="'.$row['type_name'].'" style="width: 20px;" />'.'
<label for="'.$row['type_name'].'" class="fil_lab" style="width: 100px;">'.$row['type_name']. '</label>';
```